# APACHE POI EXCEL XmlException: is an invalid XML character, is there any way to preprocess the excel file?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I use java and Apache POI to read .xlsx files.(60k+ rows), but I get the error.

I use the latest version maven plugin of poi and xmlbeans.

According to the related questions I found in StackOverflow, the latest poi should process files successfully with the special character.

I can replace the special character in the program by myself if it's an xml file. But it's an excel file.

The difficulty is that I have no idea to use poi read the "excel" file successfully.

Or is there any way to process the file?

I use openjdk, version: "1.8.0_171-1-redhat".

the error message like this

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unable to parse shared strings table
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.readFrom(SharedStringsTable.java:134)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.<init>(SharedStringsTable.java:111)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Character reference "&#55357" is an invalid XML character.
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3440)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1272)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1259)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.SstDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.readFrom(SharedStringsTable.java:123)
```

the code

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
public class test2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("D:\\Users\\3389\\Desktop\\Review\\drive-download-20181112T012605Z-001\\ticket.xlsx");
    Workbook workbook = null;
    XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file); //error occured
    workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(xssfWorkbook);
    Sheet sheet = xssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);  
    System.out.println("the first row:"+sheet.getFirstRowNum());
  }
}
```

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

UTF16SurrogatePairs in the shareString.xml (several examples)

```
&#55357;&#56397;&#55357;&#56397;&#55357;&#56397;
&#55357;&#56397;
&#55357;&#56397;&#55357;&#56397;&#55357;&#56397;&#55357;&#56397;&#55357;&#56397;&#55357;&#56397;&#55357;&#56397;
etc....
```

Comment: There definitelly is something wrong with the `/xl/sharedStrings.xml` in the `ticket.xlsx` ZIP archive. Where is that `ticket.xlsx` file coming from? What happens if you are opening that `ticket.xlsx` using `Excel`?

Comment: The excel filse is from our business parter(Chinese).  It looks fine when I use Excel to open the files.

Comment: I believe it is nearly impossible to help without having the file`ticket.xlsx` then. What happens if you are opening that `ticket.xlsx` using `Excel`, do resaving it using `Excel`? Is `apache poi` then able reading the shared strings XML properly? What happens if you are unzipping the `ticket.xlsx` and extracting `/xl/sharedStrings.xml`? Are you able opening this XML file properly using a browser or a XML reader?

Comment: I am sorry I can't disclose the files and I am not able to open the xml file properly.
I surmise the content contains special character.

Comment: "I surmise the content contains special character.": Special character would not be a problem. But `&#55357` is not a special character but a part of a UTF-16 surrogate pair for unicode characters above 0xFFFF. This character reference must not occur in Office Open XML since there the encoding must be UTF-8. So definitelly your `ticket.xlsx` is broken in `/xl/sharedStrings.xml`.

Comment: is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Yes, I found the word "&#55357"...etc  in /xl/sharedStrings.xml.  There are emoji.

Comment: Can you please show at least that part of XML in `/xl/sharedStrings.xml` in your question? You told me that "it looks fine when you use Excel to open the files.". But if I have `<si><t>ABC&#55357;&#56833;</t></si>` in `/xl/sharedStrings.xml` then my `Excel` is **not** able opening the file. And this is correct since `&#55357;&#56833;` is **not** UTF-8. It is UTF-16 in two surogate pairs. In `/xl/sharedStrings.xml` it should be `<si><t>ABC&#x1F601;</t></si>` or `<si><t>ABC</t></si>` encoded in UTF-8. Note XML and HTML are not the same things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question title contains the question "Is there any way to preprocess the excel file?", I will try a answer about that:

Assumes:
The `/xl/sharedStrings.xml` in the `*.xlsx` file contains UTF-16-surrogate-pair XML numeric character references like `&#55357;&#56833;` = . This is OK for HTML. But it is not allowed in Office Open XML because there the encoding is UTF-8 always and both the surrogate characters are not allowed in that XML.

So if the `/xl/sharedStrings.xml` in the `*.xlsx` file contains UTF-16-surrogate-pair XML numeric character references then the file is corrupt and should not be used anyway. The problem should be solved from those who have created that `*.xlsx` file.

But if nevertheless the need is repairing that file, then this can only be done on string level. Parsing XML is not possible because of the UTF-16-surrogate-pair XML numeric character references. Then the need is getting the `/xl/sharedStrings.xml` out of the `*.xlsx` file. Then get the string content of that `/xl/sharedStrings.xml` file. Then replace each found UTF-16-surrogate-pair XML numeric character reference with it's Unicode replacement.

My code shows how to do this using `java.util.regex.Matcher`. It searches for entities matching the pattern `&#(\\d{5});&#(\\d{5});`. If found it gets the surrogate pair `H`igh and `L`ow as integers. Then it checks whether this are really surrogate pairs ( `H` must be between 0xD800 and 0xDBFF and `L` must be between 0xDC00 and 0xDFFF). If so it calculates N as `N = (H - 0xD800) * 0x400 + (L - 0xDC00) + 0x10000`. Then it replaces the UTF-16-surrogate-pair XML numeric character reference with a Unicode numeric character reference. After that all it replaces leftover single parts of supplement pairs with empty string. So they will be removed since single parts of supplement pairs are not allowed.

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;
import java.util.regex.Pattern; 
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class XSSFWrongXMLinSharedStrings {

 static String replaceUTF16SurrogatePairs(String string) {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("&#(\\d{5});&#(\\d{5});");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
  while (matcher.find()) {
   String found = matcher.group();
   int h = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
   int l = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2));
   if (0xD800 <= h && h < 0xDC00 && 0xDC00 <= l && l < 0xDFFF) {
    int n = (h - 0xD800) * 0x400 + (l - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;
System.out.print(found + " will be replaced with ");
System.out.println("&#" + n + ";");
    string = string.replace(found, "&#" + n + ";");
   }
  }
  pattern = Pattern.compile("&#(\\d{5});");
  matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
  while (matcher.find()) {
   String found = matcher.group();
   int n = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
   if (0xD800 <= n && n < 0xDFFF) {
System.out.println(found + " is single part of supplement pair. It will be removed.");
    string = string.replace(found, "");
   }
  }  
  return string;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  File file = new File("ticket.xlsx");

  //Repairing the /xl/sharedStrings.xml on string level. Parsing XML is not possible because of the UTF-16-surrogate-pair XML numeric character references.
  OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(file);
  PackagePart packagePart = opcPackage.getPartsByName(Pattern.compile("/xl/sharedStrings.xml")).get(0);
  ByteArrayOutputStream sharedStringsBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int length;
  InputStream inputStream = packagePart.getInputStream();
  while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
   sharedStringsBytes.write(buffer, 0, length);
  }
  inputStream.close();
  String sharedStrings = sharedStringsBytes.toString("UTF-8");

  //Replace UTF-16-surrogate-pair XML numeric character reference with it's unicode replacement:
  //sharedStrings = sharedStrings.replace("&#55357;&#56833;", "&#x1F601;");
  //ToDo: Create method for replacing all possible UTF-16-surrogate-pair XML numeric character references with their unicode replacements.
  sharedStrings = replaceUTF16SurrogatePairs(sharedStrings);

  OutputStream outputStream = packagePart.getOutputStream();
  outputStream.write(sharedStrings.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  outputStream.flush();
  outputStream.close();
  opcPackage.close();
  //Now the /xl/sharedStrings.xml in the file does not contain UTF-16-surrogate-pair XML numeric character references any more.

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file); 
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);  
  System.out.println("Success.");
 }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate all the help that you offer the solution . I have already used java to unzip file and get sharedStrings.xml to parse. But I stll cannot replace all possible UTF-16-surrogate-pair XML numeric character references. Do you have any idea ? Or could give me some hints?

Comment: Another trouble is the String value contains multiple UTF-16-surrogate-pair XML numeric character references. like below &#55357;&#56836;&#55357;&#56834;&#55357;&#56836;&#55356;&#57098;&#55356;

Comment: @mike.jiang: I only assumed there are references like `&#55357;&#56833;`. You never told that in your question. But you should tell that in your question with at least some examples to make the question more clear. Then next step is to find all of those references in XML text and, if found, replacing them with Unicode. That would worth another question. Multiple possibilities are coming in mind: Parsing as UTF-16 HTML and then converting that HTML to Unicode UTF-8 then. Or calculating the Unicode N from the found surrogate pairs H and L: `N = (H - 0xD800) * 0x400 + (L - 0xDC00) + 0x10000`...

Comment: @mike.jiang: Or hand back those defect files to the ones who have created them. Those guys definitely have done it wrong. They should repairing it now. This is what I would do.

Comment: @mike.jiang: See my supplement for **one** example of how to do.

Comment: Thank you so much. it works. you do gave me a big favor.