# when read excel how to skip some invalid characters

Tags: apache-poi

Read some excel using poi failed, encountered such an error

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file://; lineNumber: 105; columnNumber: 147342; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xffff) was found in the element content of the document.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
```

From `xl/sharedStrings.xml`, there exist `<ffff>` cause this problem.

How could read it successfully and just ignore these invalid characters? e.g.

```
aaa <ffff> bbb ==> aaa bbb
```

Comment: Where is that Excel file coming from? Because those characters should not be in the XML and Excel itself will not put them into there. So someone probably had done something wrong while creating that file. That error should be avoided rather than trying to ignore the symptoms.

Comment: @AxelRichter Program auto download excel from third party site and then merge these excel to one, and I have given feedback to them, but cannot certain if they will fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those invalid characters should not be in the XML and Excel itself will not put them into there. So someone probably had done something wrong while creating that file using something else than Excel. That error should be avoided rather than trying to ignore the symptoms.

But I know how it feels to be depemdent on others work which will be done in far future, if even. So one needs improvising. But that is in this case only possible using ugly low level methods. Because the XML is invalid, parsing XML is not possible. So only String replacing will be possible.

In [APACHE POI EXCEL XmlException: is an invalid XML character, is there any way to preprocess the excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53357802/apache-poi-excel-xmlexception-is-an-invalid-xml-character-is-there-any-way-to/53375975#53375975) I had schown this already. In that case  to replace UTF-16-surrogate-pair numeric character references which also are invalid in XML.

In following I will show a code which is more flexible to add multiple other repairing actions to `/xl/sharedStrings.xml` if necessary.

The principle is using `OPCPackage`, which is the `*.xlsx` ZIP package, to get out the `/xl/sharedStrings.xml` as text string. Then do the needed replacings and put the repaired  `/xl/sharedStrings.xml` back into the `OPCPackage`. Then do creating the `XSSFWorkbook` from that repaired `OPCPackage` instead of from the corrupt file.

```java
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class RepairSharedStringsTable {
    
 static String removeInvalidXmlCharacters(String string) {
  String xml10pattern = "[^"
                    + "\u0009\r\n"
                    + "\u0020-\uD7FF"
                    + "\uE000-\uFFFD"
                    + "\ud800\udc00-\udbff\udfff"
                    + "]";
  string = string.replaceAll(xml10pattern, "");
  return string;     
 }
    
 static void repairSharedStringsTable(OPCPackage opcPackage) {
  for (PackagePart packagePart : opcPackage.getPartsByName(Pattern.compile("/xl/sharedStrings.xml"))) {
   
   String sharedStrings = "";
   try (BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(packagePart.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream sharedStringsBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
   
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
     sharedStringsBytes.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    sharedStrings = sharedStringsBytes.toString("UTF-8");
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
    
   System.out.println(sharedStrings);
   //sharedStrings = replaceUTF16SurrogatePairs(sharedStrings);
   sharedStrings = removeInvalidXmlCharacters(sharedStrings);
   //sharedStrings = doSomethingElse(sharedStrings);
   System.out.println(sharedStrings);

   try (BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(packagePart.getOutputStream()) ) {
    outputStream.write(sharedStrings.getBytes("UTF-8"));
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  }  
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("./Excel.xlsx"))) {
   System.out.println("success");
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   System.out.println("failed");
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(new FileInputStream("./Excel.xlsx"));
  repairSharedStringsTable(opcPackage);
  opcPackage.flush();
  
  try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./ExcelRepaired.xlsx");) {
   workbook.write(out);
   System.out.println("success");
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   System.out.println("failed");
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: `removeInvalidXmlCharacters ` is ok, from the console I can see the invalid characters are removed but  when execute `XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage)` still throw exception: `An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xffff) was found in the element content of the document` it seems opcPackage not flush

Comment: @zhuguowei: The code in my answer is complete and tested and works. But it only repairs the `/xl/sharedStrings.xml`. Is your error about another paret of the `*.xlsx`? If not, what `apache poi` version are you using? Me always using the last stable version, `apach poi 5.2.0` in this case.

Comment: @zhuguowei: But putting `opcPackage.flush();` after the repairing cannot be wrong. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: In my case there are 3 xml should be processed

Answer (score 0):

In my case below files all have invalid characters

```
xl/sharedStrings.xml
xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
xl/worksheets/sheet8.xml
```

All these xml should be processed

```
opcPackage.getPartsByName(Pattern.compile("(/xl/sharedStrings.xml)|(/xl/worksheets/.+\\.xml)"))
```